# Authentic Traditional Texts On Homa Procedures?

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation, homam

Are there any authentic traditional texts on homa procedures like the Ganapathi Homa for example. I know there is a Parashuram Kalpasutra followed by some Sri Vidya lineages. Looking for others as well.

thanks

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE!  I Suggest also to add language preferences in question.